# doing a tutorial and I found that my code isn't working

Tags: javascript, html

So the code worked for the guy on the tutorial.

I then checked my code from his git repos but couldn't find any mistakes.

It's a very simple website where it just saves the values which you input in the field as a list item. It showed an error.

[image]

```js
let myLeads = []
const inputEl = document.getElementById("input-el")
const inputBtn = document.getElementById("input-btn")
const ulEl = document.getElementById("ul-el")

inputBtn.addEventListener("click", function(){
    myLeads.push(inputEl.value)
    console.log(myLeads)
})

for (let i = 0; i < myLeads.length; i++) {
    ulEl.innerHTML += "<li>" + myLeads[i] + "</li>"
}
```

```css
body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
input{
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid green;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
button{
    background-color: green;
    color: antiquewhite;
    height: 50px;
    width: 150px;
    border: 0ch;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="ChromeEx.css">
</head>
<body>
   <input type="text" id="input-el">
    <button class="input-btn">SAVE INPUT</button>
    <ul id="ul-el"></ul>
    <script src="ChromeEx.js" defer></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using `const inputBtn = document.getElementById("input-btn")` to get the button, but it does not have an id, you need to add an id for the button

So change

```
<button class="input-btn">SAVE INPUT</button>
```

to

```
<button id="input-btn" class="input-btn">SAVE INPUT</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

To help you resolve issues like this in the future, you need to know how to interpret the error shown in the developer console. What it's saying is that you're trying to interact with or access something that doesn't exist (`null`). This means the variable you're using (`inputBtn`) holds the value `null`.

[image]

It's pretty clear then that what you thought you were assigning to this variable didn't work out the way you expected. The assignment code looks good, so we can be sure that the `getElementById()` method is not "returning" the intended value. Indeed, that method will return `null` when the `id` given to it is not found in the html.

Comment: Thanks for helping me I am still learning so thx